Error: Prisma Migrate has detected that the environment is non-interactive, which is not supported
I want to create new table add schema.prima:


model REF_DOMAIN_GSTANDARDS {
  Data_Domain_GS String? @db.VarChar(Max) 
  DomainGSID    Int     @id@default(autoincrement()) 
}



then i run in cmdnpx prisma migrate dev --name add_ref_domain_gstandards
but got error:
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": SQL Server database
Error: Prisma Migrate has detected that the environment is non-interactive, which is not supported.
prisma migrate dev is an interactive command designed to create new migrations and evolve the database in development.
To apply existing migrations in deployments, use prisma migrate deploy.
